# Pandas - reading from SQL server, and outputting to csv - encoding problems

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, pandas, encoding

I am reading data into pandas from an SQL Server 2014 12.0.4100 SP1 database.  The data is stored in the Windows-1252 encoding.

I am using python 2.7.

I want to output the resulting dataframe to Excel or csv.  Specifically:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=.\my_server;Database=my_db;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
sql = "select * from my_table"
df = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn)
df.to_csv("my_csv.csv", encoding="utf-8")
```

However, this fails with the error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 13966: invalid start byte
```

What do I need to do to successfully export to a utf-8 csv?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to convert any columns with non-ASCII characters to UTF-8 explicitly.

You can do this using the following code:

```
def convert(my_str):
    return my_str.decode('Windows-1252').encode('utf-8')
df["Name"] = df["Name"].apply(convert)
```

Once converted, you will be able to write to .csv and Excel format without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use 'ISO-8859-2' as the encoding ?

```
df.to_csv("my_csv.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-2")
```